# Change (or Centralise) Property Value for all Controls on a WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, telerik

New to WPF so I'm sure it's an easy one this; for every control of a certain type/s, I want to set a property to the same value. The property is telerik:Theming.Theme and I would like to apply the same value to all telerik: controls. If there's no way to do this then how do I use a resource to define this value and refer to the resource in the controls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may override the default value of any dependency property for a specific control type (precisely a specific type of dependency object) by [DependencyProperty.OverrideMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597491.aspx) in your application initialization code (e.g. the static constructor of your MainWindow):

```
Telerik.Windows.Controls.Theming.ThemeProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(SomeControlClass),
    new PropertyMetadata(SomeDefaultValue));
```

where SomeControlClass is the (base) class that you want to give a new default value for the Theme property, and SomeDefaultValue is the new default value.

Note also that `Theming.ThemeProperty` seems to be obsolete and will be replaced by `StyleManager.ThemeProperty`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this sorted it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to define a *resource* for binding, but you need to define a *property* on `ModelView` and bind it to every control.

Comment: How do I define a property on ModelView?

Comment: @DanielMcNulty: it's a basically a simple property when notify to binding of WPF when it's changed. [Here](http://blogs.u2u.be/peter/post/2010/03/20/Using-Model-View-ViewModel-with-WPF.aspx) is a good example of how to define and consume them.